# jQUery plugin issue in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I have created my jQuery custom plugin as;

```
(function($){

$.fn.userForm = function(){
var element = this;
var UserDataObj = {
name:"John",
email:"john@example.com",
phone:"9999999999",
desc:"some description"
}


        this.supports_html5_storage = function() 
        {

        };


        this.saveFormData = function(param)
        {


        }


        if (this.supports_html5_storage())
        {

        }
        else
        {

        }



};

})(jQuery);
```

Now I am trying to call a method within my plug in as;

```
var myPlugin = new $.fn.userForm();
myPlugin.saveFormData(".formFieldUserData");
```

For some reason, the code breaks in IE while executing 
var myPlugin = new $.fn.userForm();

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Breaks how? What error messages do you get?

Comment: It says Unable to get value of the property 'toLowerCase': object is null or undefined (points to the jQuery js)

Comment: I tested your code in jsFiddle and locally, I dont get the error in IE7 or IE9. Make sure theres not anything else in this file that could be causingt he error. If it only occurs in IE then look for missing commas or semi-colons.

Comment: I am getting the issue on IE9...I use doctype html (for html5)

Comment: I am not returning anything from my plugin..Can that be the issue ?